# EKEventStore authorizationStatusForEntityType: not recognized?

Tags: ios, ekeventstore

I'm trying to check if my app was granted access to the user's Reminders by using:

```
EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

EKAuthorizationStatus status = [store authorizationStatusForEntityType:EKEntityTypeReminder];
```

But Xcode says there is no visible @interface for 'authorizationStatusForEntityType:', when clearly there is. What's making it do this and how can I fix it? (it's not like this is a private method, it's in the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventStoreClassRef/Reference/Reference.html)...)

PS. I've already restarted Xcode and my Mac, cleaned the project and everything...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the `EKEventStore` variable. Just use:

```
EKAuthorizationStatus status = [EKEventStore authorizationStatusForEntityType:EKEntityTypeReminder];
```

`authorizationStatusForEntityType:` is a static method; you don't need an independent variable.